# NextResponse does not run catch block when response code is an error

Tags: javascript, http, next.js

Im trying to do a simple request inside try/catch block, that returns an error on Next 13 (app router), however even if the status code is error (4xx ~ 5xx), catch block is not executing.

im using Next Route Handlers for the api

the handler:

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
    return NextResponse.json({error: 'Returning an error'}, {status: 500})
}
```

here is the method that is doing the request:

```
async function doRequest() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/users/signup", {
        method: "POST"
      })
      console.log("response here: ", response)
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log("error here: ", error)
    }
  }
```

this method lives in a client component

in the network tab, i can see that the request is returning error with status code 500

also the response.ok property in this case is false, but it is not causing the catch block to execute

what could it be?

Comment: `fetch()` does not throw an exception on HTTP error code responses.

Comment: oh interesting, so a proper way to handle this would be to throw an exception in case response.ok is false?

Comment: Yes, if having an exception thrown is important for your application. The idea for `fetch()` is that an error from the server is just as much a success as a 200; in both cases, `fetch()` has succeeded in making the HTTP request happen, so it's OK with error results and dealing with that is your application's problem.